# I get error message "runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0" when I try to start minikube

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube

Maybe this a newbie question, I am  installing minikube. When I try to start minikube (`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "MiniKube" --alsologtostderr -v=8 --memory=2000`) I see an error message in the log (`panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0`):

```
I0410 07:24:15.123609    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive @(Get-Module -ListAvailable hyper-v).Name | Get-Unique
I0410 07:24:15.339794    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [stdout =====>] :
I0410 07:24:15.339794    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [stderr =====>] :
I0410 07:24:15.340756    1724 client.go:172] LocalClient.Create took 586.3704ms
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

This is the complete log:

```
PS C:\> minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "MiniKube" --alsologtostderr -v=8 --memory=2000
W0410 01:15:52.776702      72 root.go:248] Error reading config file at C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\config\config.json: open C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\config\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
I0410 01:15:52.780691      72 notify.go:125] Checking for updates...
I0410 01:15:53.293167      72 start.go:262] hostinfo: {"hostname":"DESKTOP-TVHSQJC","uptime":1563,"bootTime":1586497790,"procs":191,"os":"windows","platform":"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language","platformFamily":"Standalone Workstation","platformVersion":"10.0.18362 Build 18362","kernelVersion":"","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"","hostid":"33e72451-872e-4673-b23d-c29f75f4dc35"}
W0410 01:15:53.293167      72 start.go:270] gopshost.Virtualization returned error: not implemented yet
* minikube v1.9.2 en Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.18362 Build 18362
I0410 01:15:53.362980      72 driver.go:245] Setting default libvirt URI to qemu:///system
* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
I0410 01:15:54.783789      72 start.go:310] selected driver: hyperv
I0410 01:15:54.784786      72 start.go:656] validating driver "hyperv" against <nil>
I0410 01:15:54.788061      72 start.go:662] status for hyperv: {Installed:true Healthy:true Error:<nil> Fix: Doc:}
I0410 01:15:54.788775      72 start.go:1210] Wait components to verify : map[apiserver:true system_pods:true]
I0410 01:15:54.789771      72 iso.go:119] acquiring lock: {Name:mk489b460911118cd1582e81f0bed446f9566f30 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:10m0s Cancel:<nil>}
* Downloading VM boot image ...
I0410 01:15:54.814975      72 iso.go:147] full url: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso?checksum=file:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso.sha256
    > minikube-v1.9.0.iso.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > minikube-v1.9.0.iso: 174.93 MiB / 174.93 MiB [ 100.00% 1.82 MiB p/s 1m36s
* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
I0410 01:17:33.260532      72 preload.go:81] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.18.0 and runtime docker
I0410 01:17:33.538319      72 preload.go:114] Found remote preload: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4
I0410 01:17:33.538319      72 cache.go:46] Caching tarball of preloaded images
I0410 01:17:33.542306      72 preload.go:81] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.18.0 and runtime docker
I0410 01:17:33.643204      72 preload.go:114] Found remote preload: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4
* Downloading Kubernetes v1.18.0 preload ...
I0410 01:17:33.669080      72 preload.go:144] Downloading: &{Ctx:<nil> Src:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4 Dst:C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\cache\preloaded-tarball\preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4.download Pwd: Mode:2 Detectors:[] Decompressors:map[] Getters:map[] Dir:false ProgressListener:<nil> Options:[0xc15670]}
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: 542.91 MiB
I0410 01:22:35.483647      72 preload.go:160] saving checksum for preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4 ...
I0410 01:22:35.794173      72 preload.go:177] verifying checksumm of C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\cache\preloaded-tarball\preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4.download ...
I0410 01:22:37.049807      72 cache.go:49] Finished downloading the preloaded tar for v1.18.0 on docker
I0410 01:22:37.050808      72 profile.go:138] Saving config to C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json ...
I0410 01:22:37.051804      72 lock.go:35] WriteFile acquiring C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json: {Name:mk135836da876aa669fb2d39bc4acd571651f245 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:1m0s Cancel:<nil>}
I0410 01:22:37.061190      72 cache.go:117] Successfully downloaded all kic artifacts
I0410 01:22:37.061190      72 start.go:260] acquiring machines lock for minikube: {Name:mk72c8971e0e6c4ad7d34035b9e15502a51a2ea9 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:15m0s Cancel:<nil>}
I0410 01:22:37.062189      72 start.go:264] acquired machines lock for "minikube" in 0s
I0410 01:22:37.065183      72 start.go:86] Provisioning new machine with config: {Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso Memory:2000 CPUs:2 DiskSize:20000 Driver:hyperv HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.99.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch:MiniKube HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ClusterName:minikube APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false NodeIP: NodePort:0 NodeName:} Nodes:[{Name:m01 IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}] Addons:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true system_pods:true]} {Name:m01 IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}
I0410 01:22:37.065183      72 start.go:107] createHost starting for "m01" (driver="hyperv")
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
I0410 01:22:37.131796      72 start.go:143] libmachine.API.Create for "minikube" (driver="hyperv")
I0410 01:22:37.132794      72 client.go:169] LocalClient.Create starting
I0410 01:22:37.136784      72 main.go:110] libmachine: Creating CA: C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\certs\ca.pem
I0410 01:22:37.277444      72 main.go:110] libmachine: Creating client certificate: C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\certs\cert.pem
I0410 01:22:37.618494      72 main.go:110] libmachine: [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive @(Get-Module -ListAvailable hyper-v).Name | Get-Unique
I0410 01:22:37.838183      72 main.go:110] libmachine: [stdout =====>] :
I0410 01:22:37.838183      72 main.go:110] libmachine: [stderr =====>] :
I0410 01:22:37.839147      72 client.go:172] LocalClient.Create took 703.289ms
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 162 [running]:
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.hypervAvailable(0xc0003b4630, 0xc00021f3f0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/powershell.go:64 +0x105
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.(*Driver).PreCreateCheck(0xc0005d4ba0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/hyperv.go:171 +0x3b
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.(*LocalClient).Create(0xc000216340, 0xc0005d4c00, 0x0, 0x0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/client.go:229 +0x3f5
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost.func2(0x1e08b00, 0xc000216340, 0xc0005d4c00, 0xc0002771d0, 0xc0005300e0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:170 +0x42
created by k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:169 +0x10e
PS C:\> minikube delete
! "minikube" profile does not exist, trying anyways.
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
PS C:\> minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "MiniKube" --alsologtostderr -v=8 --memory=2000
I0410 07:17:24.557312    1724 notify.go:125] Checking for updates...
I0410 07:17:25.094876    1724 start.go:262] hostinfo: {"hostname":"DESKTOP-TVHSQJC","uptime":23254,"bootTime":1586497791,"procs":216,"os":"windows","platform":"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language","platformFamily":"Standalone Workstation","platformVersion":"10.0.18362 Build 18362","kernelVersion":"","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"","hostid":"33e72451-872e-4673-b23d-c29f75f4dc35"}
W0410 07:17:25.094876    1724 start.go:270] gopshost.Virtualization returned error: not implemented yet
* minikube v1.9.2 en Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.18362 Build 18362
I0410 07:17:25.200591    1724 driver.go:245] Setting default libvirt URI to qemu:///system
* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
I0410 07:17:26.923910    1724 start.go:310] selected driver: hyperv
I0410 07:17:26.923910    1724 start.go:656] validating driver "hyperv" against <nil>
I0410 07:17:26.923910    1724 start.go:662] status for hyperv: {Installed:true Healthy:true Error:<nil> Fix: Doc:}
I0410 07:17:26.924950    1724 start.go:1210] Wait components to verify : map[apiserver:true system_pods:true]
I0410 07:17:26.924950    1724 iso.go:119] acquiring lock: {Name:mk489b460911118cd1582e81f0bed446f9566f30 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:10m0s Cancel:<nil>}
* Downloading VM boot image ...
I0410 07:17:26.959728    1724 iso.go:147] full url: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso?checksum=file:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso.sha256
    > minikube-v1.9.0.iso.sha256: 65 B / 65 B [--------------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > minikube-v1.9.0.iso: 174.93 MiB / 174.93 MiB [ 100.00% 1.80 MiB p/s 1m37s
* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
I0410 07:19:06.392837    1724 preload.go:81] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.18.0 and runtime docker
I0410 07:19:06.811093    1724 preload.go:114] Found remote preload: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4
I0410 07:19:06.812115    1724 cache.go:46] Caching tarball of preloaded images
I0410 07:19:06.818091    1724 preload.go:81] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.18.0 and runtime docker
I0410 07:19:06.938300    1724 preload.go:114] Found remote preload: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4
* Downloading Kubernetes v1.18.0 preload ...
I0410 07:19:06.963740    1724 preload.go:144] Downloading: &{Ctx:<nil> Src:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube-preloaded-volume-tarballs/preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4 Dst:C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\cache\preloaded-tarball\preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4.download Pwd: Mode:2 Detectors:[] Decompressors:map[] Getters:map[] Dir:false ProgressListener:<nil> Options:[0xc15670]}
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: 542.91 MiB
I0410 07:24:12.620296    1724 preload.go:160] saving checksum for preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4 ...
I0410 07:24:13.151132    1724 preload.go:177] verifying checksumm of C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\cache\preloaded-tarball\preloaded-images-k8s-v2-v1.18.0-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4.download ...
I0410 07:24:14.351294    1724 cache.go:49] Finished downloading the preloaded tar for v1.18.0 on docker
I0410 07:24:14.351294    1724 profile.go:138] Saving config to C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json ...
I0410 07:24:14.352249    1724 lock.go:35] WriteFile acquiring C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json: {Name:mk135836da876aa669fb2d39bc4acd571651f245 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:1m0s Cancel:<nil>}
I0410 07:24:14.634215    1724 cache.go:117] Successfully downloaded all kic artifacts
I0410 07:24:14.634215    1724 start.go:260] acquiring machines lock for minikube: {Name:mk72c8971e0e6c4ad7d34035b9e15502a51a2ea9 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:15m0s Cancel:<nil>}
I0410 07:24:14.635218    1724 start.go:264] acquired machines lock for "minikube" in 0s
I0410 07:24:14.639240    1724 start.go:86] Provisioning new machine with config: {Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO:https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.9.0.iso Memory:2000 CPUs:2 DiskSize:20000 Driver:hyperv HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.99.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch:MiniKube HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ClusterName:minikube APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false NodeIP: NodePort:0 NodeName:} Nodes:[{Name:m01 IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}] Addons:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true system_pods:true]} {Name:m01 IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.18.0 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}
I0410 07:24:14.639240    1724 start.go:107] createHost starting for "m01" (driver="hyperv")
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
I0410 07:24:14.750393    1724 start.go:143] libmachine.API.Create for "minikube" (driver="hyperv")
I0410 07:24:14.753426    1724 client.go:169] LocalClient.Create starting
I0410 07:24:14.755381    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: Creating CA: C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\certs\ca.pem
I0410 07:24:14.928984    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: Creating client certificate: C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\certs\cert.pem
I0410 07:24:15.123609    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive @(Get-Module -ListAvailable hyper-v).Name | Get-Unique
I0410 07:24:15.339794    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [stdout =====>] :
I0410 07:24:15.339794    1724 main.go:110] libmachine: [stderr =====>] :
I0410 07:24:15.340756    1724 client.go:172] LocalClient.Create took 586.3704ms
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 164 [running]:
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.hypervAvailable(0xc0003ee8d0, 0xc000266a90)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/powershell.go:64 +0x105
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.(*Driver).PreCreateCheck(0xc000592420, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/hyperv.go:171 +0x3b
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.(*LocalClient).Create(0xc000218d80, 0xc000592480, 0x0, 0x0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/client.go:229 +0x3f5
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost.func2(0x1e08b00, 0xc000218d80, 0xc000592480, 0xc000215100, 0xc00005e230)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:170 +0x42
created by k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:169 +0x10e
```

I would like if starting process was executed successfully.

PD: I deactived firewall when execute the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues you are encountering are strictly connected with this line:

```bsh
minikube v1.9.2 en Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.18362 Build 18362
```

**Windows 10 Home does not support `Hyper-V`**.

Citing official Microsoft page:

> Enable Hyper-V to create virtual machines on Windows 10.
>   Hyper-V can be enabled in many ways including using the Windows 10 control panel, PowerShell or using the Deployment Imaging Servicing and Management tool (DISM). This documents walks through each option.
>
> > **Note:**  Hyper-V is built into Windows as an optional feature -- there is no Hyper-V download.
>
> ### Check Requirements
>
> - **Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education**
> - 64-bit Processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
> - CPU support for VM Monitor Mode Extension (VT-c on Intel CPUs).
> - Minimum of 4 GB memory.
>
> --  [Docs.microsoft.com: Virtualization: Enable hyper v](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

**As you can see there is a requirement that forbids using `Hyper-V` with `Windows 10 Home`.**

For your `minikube` to work you can either:

- Use a different Hypervisor like for example [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and then start `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`
- [Upgrade](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro) your `Windows 10` to version that officially supports `Hyper-V`