# docker command does not work in PowerShell (Windows 10 Home)?

Tags: powershell, docker, minikube

Well, [I am trying to instal minikube in a PC with Windows 10 Home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140329/i-get-error-message-runtime-error-index-out-of-range-0-with-length-0-when-i).

I am following this tutorial:

https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows

I am in the step where I should execute the following command in PowerShell:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

I got this error:

```
En línea: 1 Carácter: 7
+ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
+       ~
Debe proporcionar una expresión de valor después del operador '/'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 7
+ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
+       ~
Token 'f' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 53
+ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
+                                                     ~
Token no reconocido en el texto de origen.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
+ ~~~~
El operador de expansión '@' no se puede usar para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión. '@FOR' solamente se
puede usar como argumento para un comando. Para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión, use '$FOR'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

So, I decided to continue the tutorial using cmd. Finally I could complete the tutorial.

I thought the first sequence command failed in PowerShell by a problem related to syntax. But I don't understand why `docker ps` command fail
 in PowerShell. I get the following error in PowerShell:

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

I would like to know why docker command is not working in my PowerShell window?

PD: I open PowerShell with admin privileges.

**UPDATE 1**

According to @BACON's suggestion I execute this command sequence:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO %i
```

But I get an error:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

As users said in the comments. The commands mentioned in the tutorial for starting minikube works in cmd don't in PowerShell. If We have take in account that, the tutorial can be completed successfully.

Comment: The `@FOR...` command is specific to the `Command Prompt` interpreter, not PowerShell, so the tutorial is wrong in that regard.  Although, if you encountered and subsequently solved that problem it doesn't really need to be in the question.  What would be more useful is to specify what commands you have executed, in which shell, and as which user.

Comment: I an following the tutorial. I have problem with this command: `docker ps`. I get an error when I execute in PowerShell

Comment: I understand that, but one should not have to visit an external website to see what commands you're running.  See [MCVE] where it says to "Provide all parts ... to reproduce your problem _in the question itself_".  You also say you switched shells halfway through, which is why I'm suggesting you explicitly list not only the exact commands you have executed to this point, but also in which shell and as what user.  Also, what is the output of `minikube docker-env`?  The tutorial says "Please note that you should type the above command every time you open a new terminal", so that's needed in PS.

Comment: When I executed the command sequence: `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i` in CMD I don't get an output. CMD don't show any output. I though it doesn't work in PowerShell due to a syntax problem. But I don't understand why `docker ps` command doesn't work in PowerShell. Its output is in the question.

Comment: That syntax won't work in PowerShell, but evidently you need the effect of that command to be performed _in the same shell_ before you can proceed with `docker ps`.  The effect of that command is to run `minikube docker-env`, take each line of the resulting output, and run it as a command.  Try running `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO %i` (notice the `@` removed near the end) in `cmd` and it should show the commands being executed.

Comment: I update my question. That sequence command that you suggested failed

Comment: You're trying to run batch commands in PowerShell. That's not going to work. If you want to use batch commands, don't do it in PowerShell. The powershell equivalent would be something like `(minikube docker-env) % { $_ }`. Or put `cmd` in front of the command you're trying to run: `cmd FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO %i`

Comment: Regarding the edit, you are again running the `FOR` command in PowerShell.  As I said it needs to be run in `cmd`.

Comment: They're trying to explain that the article is slightly wrong man...
He has a powershell client and it is suppose to be ran with CMD client.

Comment: @DanielMann I haven't noticed that BACON have mentioned that I should execute commands in cmd. Well, my problem is solved: Commands can run successfully in cmd. The tutorial seems to be wrong when it mentions PowerShell. Thanks at all!

Comment: Please consider posting an answer if the problem is solved. It would be easier to find by the rest of the community.

Comment: @OhHiMark ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved my proble running the commands in cmd don't in PowerShell.

The command for starting docker in Windows works in cmd (Windows 10 Home Edition) is:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO %i
```

If you want to run docker in Power Shell, you should execute this command:

```
minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

In my case when I executed command `minikube docker-env` :

```
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.101:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\Cesar\.minikube\certs"
$Env:MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD = "minikube"
# To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
# & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

PD: I'm using minikube